# Stored procedure in pgsql to create materialized views

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in pgsql that creates a materialized view with data from a specific year from a table. The parameters will be the table name, the column that contains the year, and the year.

I know that in SQL Server it would be something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createMaterializedView 
    @tablename varchar(100), 
    @column varchar(100), 
    @year integer
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return varchar(1000) = 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view_' + @tablename + '_' + @year + 'AS SELECT * from' + @tablename + 'where'
    + @column + ' = ' + @year

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @return
END
```

In pgsql, what I got right now is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createMaterializedView(tablename varchar(100), column varchar (100), year integer)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS  $$

BEGIN
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "view_" + $tablename + "_" + $year 
    AS 
    SELECT * from tablename
    WHERE column = year
END;
$$;
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: there isn't such thing as `MATERIALIZED VIEW` in `SQL Server`

Comment: I know that, the materialized view is a feature in pgsql, I just put the code in sql server to ilustrate what I kind wanted to do with the procedure

Comment: Did you search for running dynamic SQL in plpgsql like you do in your TSQL example?

Comment: Variable names don't start with a `$` in PL/pgSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a dynamic query, formatted for your identifiers (view name, table, column) and literal value (year) to be run using `EXECUTE`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_materialized_view (
    _tablename varchar(100), 
    _column varchar(100), 
    _year integer
) 
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS 
$proc$ 
DECLARE 
    _vw text := 'view_' || _tablename || '_' || _year;
    _sql text := 
        'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW %I AS
         SELECT * FROM %I WHERE %I = %L';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(_sql, _vw, _tablename, _column, _year);
END
$proc$
```

Comment: Looks good, except that procedures don't return anything.

Comment: It almost works, but when i call the procedure, it doesn't change the $1 for the variable year. Here's a example of the query returned:

SQL statement "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "view_T222RVUN_2017" AS
         SELECT * FROM "T222RVUN" WHERE "AA_REF" = $1"

Comment: I actually got what I wanted replacing the $1 for %L, and adding the parameter year int the execute. I was having some difficult to understand how dinamic SQL works in pgsql, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm... the recommended `USING` is supposed to bind the `_year` to `$1` placeholder. See [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You should never actually *see* the parameter replacing the placeholder with prepared SQL statement. What error did you receive with `USING`?

Comment: Well, I belive the error was that the code didn't bind the year. The exact output was this:
ERROR:  materialized views may not be defined using bound parameters
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "view_T222RSVN_2018" AS
         SELECT * FROM "T222RSVN" WHERE "AA_REF" = $1"

Comment: Got it. Yes, much clearer error. And that makes sense since the SQL is saved with the view so literal values cannot be parameterized but must be interpolated! Adjusting answer accordingly.